# Devilbox pgMyAdmin Error Cannot change session name when session is active

Tags: php, phppgadmin

Hello I'm totally new to devilbox, I've installed it without errors but when I'm trying to log into pgmyadmin I'm getting the following warnings:

Warning: session_name(): Cannot change session name when session is active in /var/www/default/htdocs/vendor/phppgadmin-7.12.0/libraries/lib.inc.php on line 55

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /var/www/default/htdocs/vendor/phppgadmin-7.12.0/libraries/lib.inc.php:55) in /var/www/default/htdocs/vendor/phppgadmin-7.12.0/classes/Misc.php on line 526

Can you guys help?

Answer (score 0):

Hey looks like a bug related to having php warnings active, I did a workaround on my setup by adding a `.user.ini` in the phppgadmin folder to disable errors here `.devilbox\www\htdocs\vendor\phppgadmin-7.12.0\.user.ini`.

My config file was just this:

```
display_errors = Off
display_startup_errors = Off
html_errors = 0
error_reporting = 1
```

Answer (score -1):

there is a pull request for this https://github.com/cytopia/devilbox/pull/729#issuecomment-698531140

Comment: "Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline." See [How To Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)